# Pyspark: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HOUR_OF_DAY: 0 -> 1

Tags: apache-spark, datetime, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have pyspark data frame when I convert string to date for calculating age group of its given an error : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HOUR_OF_DAY: 0 -> 1

```
final_df = final_df.withColumn('dob',to_date(unix_timestamp(col('DateOfBirth'),'yyyy-MM-dd').cast("timestamp")))
```

when I run this it's given error : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HOUR_OF_DAY: 0 -> 1

Answer (score 0):

I think the line you have posted works fine if the date format of the strings that you parse are correct. But I think you can skip the `F.unix_timestamp` function.
Here is a small self-contained example that parse strings in the format you have specified:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
sample_dates = ['2021-09-01',
                '2021-10-01',
                '2021-03-01',
                '2010-07-10']
df = spark.createDataFrame([(date,) for date in sample_dates], ["string_dates"])

df_with_date = df.withColumn('timestamp_dates', F.to_date('string_dates', 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
df_with_date.show()
print(df_with_date.schema)
```

Output:

```
+------------+---------------+
|string_dates|timestamp_dates|
+------------+---------------+
|  2021-09-01|     2021-09-01|
|  2021-10-01|     2021-10-01|
|  2021-03-01|     2021-03-01|
|  2010-07-10|     2010-07-10|
+------------+---------------+

StructType(List(StructField(string_dates,StringType,true),StructField(timestamp_dates,DateType,true)))
```